# How do I return a value from a new object, whilst keeping its methods

Tags: javascript

So I have code like so:

```
function set(a) {
  this.foo = function(){
    alert('bar');
  }

  return a;
}

var b = new set([2,3,4]);

b; //returns [2,3,4]
b.foo(); //undefined function
```

I would like to return the array input as the return value of the new set, rather than having to attach it to a property e.g. `this.arr = a;`

How can I achieve this without wiping the foo method from the object?

Comment: why not a.foo = function ?, but you should remove the 'new'

Comment: In that context, `this` refers to the window object, so you're really attaching `foo` to the global namespace.

Comment: @Nit Unless there was an edit to the post, `set()` is being called as a constructor, so `this` should refer to the `new` instance rather than the global object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this, I think!

```
function set(a) {
  a.foo = function(){
    alert('bar');
  }

  return a;
}

var b = new set([2,3,4]);

b; //returns [2,3,4]
b.foo(); //this shows alert
```

Comment: Genius! How did I not think of that!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand properly what you're after, you need:

```
function set(a) {
  a.foo = function(){
    alert('bar');
  }
  return a;
}

var b = new set([2,3,4]);
b.foo(); //alerts
```

...i.e. attach the method to the input, not, as you were, to the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
function set(a) {
  var o = {};

  o.foo = function(){
    alert('bar');
  };
  return o;
}
```

Should be what you want - you do not need the parameter.

Comment: Actually, OP wants a set to contain an array.

Comment: Also, it needs to return the parameter. not an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the constructor clean and if you want  to keep this.foo inside set()  you probably should  add `new set().foo` method to `Array.prototype`

```
function set(a) {

   this.foo = function(){
    alert('bar');
  };

   return a;

}
Array.prototype.foo=new set().foo;
var b = new set([2,3,4]);

console.log(b); //returns [2,3,4]
b.foo();// alerts 'bar'
```

Comment: Solution looks like it works, but I would prefer not to add methods to the Array prototype if they are only related to my set object.